# High Sierra- Partition error

Tags: bootcamp, disk-utility, partition, high-sierra, error

I have boot camped the Mac to have windows. I had an issue so deleted windows during setup to reinstall on the partition. In this process I think I have lost my recovery for Mac as its just all fallen apart from there.

So gone into disk utility to delete the partition to restart it now I am not seeing the partition at all and when I try to resize the Mac one its not allowing me too as it comes with an error that it cannot find the other partition that windows was on.

Now I tried to do a full reset using command R and do the internet one but I get stuck on the apple sign after that so have to restart. If I was to boot the Mac to single mode using command s it takes me to the black screen no bootable device found please insert disk well something like that. Even tried to do clean install of windows but it gets to partition bit it says that partition is formatted in a different way it won't work on it.

When I open finder under devices I have remove disc so I am assuming this is the partition that I've screwed up. I may have overlooked something but guys what can I do?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried all startup commands to try to get to the recovery screen? One of these should get you out of the black screen.

Command+R

Command+Option+R

Command+Shift+Option+R

Or

Just the option Key

Hopefully you will get into recovery mode to use terminal.
- Open Terminal and type the following command (without quotes) “diskutil list”

-Terminal should give you a breakdown of the disks and volumes that are currently on your Mac that you may not see in disk utility.

Anyway you can post the picture of diskutil list?

Also what Mac version do you have?

Comment: I managed to do all of that they didnt help

Comment: Actually put in my installation disk for windows to bring up the partitions there and noticed a hidden one that didnt appear before so managed to delete it go back to mac made the whole hard drive as one and bootcamp started to work